# Where does "rosmsg md5" get the md5sum from?

Tags: ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get my robot to work with my pc, which have two different ROS versions (due to circumstances I am not able to upgrade the robot). Therefore in a message I use, the md5sum is different and it gives the following error:

```
Client [/move_group] wants topic /move_group/goal to have datatype/md5sum [moveit_msgs/MoveGroupActionGoal/af242119c3633849fe07bc300952a4c0], but our version has [moveit_msgs/MoveGroupActionGoal/df11ac1a643d87b6e6a6fe5af1823709]. Dropping connection.
```

I figured out that the .msg file on the robot has one line missing, which is present on the .msg file on my pc. This results in the md5 hash to be different. So I tried deleting the line in the .msg file on my pc and "catkin build" my package.
Now running:

```
rosmsg show moveit_msgs/MoveGroupActionGoal | grep max_acceleration_scaling_factor
```

Gives me nothing, which means that this line is correctly deleted in the message. However when I now run:

```
rosmsg md5 moveit_msgs/MoveGroupActionGoal
```

It still gives me:

```
df11ac1a643d87b6e6a6fe5af1823709
```

Which means that it gets the md5sum from somewhere else. What I found is that in the "MoveGroupActionGoal.h" header file the md5sum is hard coded. Here I changed the return value in the MD5Sum from "df11ac1a643d87b6e6a6fe5af1823709" to "af242119c3633849fe07bc300952a4c0".

However after using "catkin build" in my package and again running:

```
rosmsg md5 moveit_msgs/MoveGroupActionGoal
```

Still gives me the wrong md5sum, hence my question is where does "rosmsg md5 moveit_msgs/MoveGroupActionGoal" gets its md5sum from? Apparently not from the .msg file and not from the header file. Thanks a lot in advance for answering.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318964/where-does-%22rosmsg-md5%22-get-the-md5sum-from?/) by [fmeccanici](https://answers.ros.org/users/40538/fmeccanici/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [winstongao](https://answers.ros.org/users/44339/winstongao/) on 2020-05-10**:
I removed every file relative with the specific package from the ROS workspace (including src, devel, build folder). Then the md5 value will not be returned after I removed the .py file in devel (I use Python to program ROS node). Then install the new package. The subscriber and publisher will have the message with the same md5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> where does "rosmsg md5 moveit_msgs/MoveGroupActionGoal" gets its md5sum from?

There are numerous Q&As that answer this, see #q233654 and #q308593 for instance.

---

As to your problem: hacking the hashes into files is not going to be a very robust or maintainable approach. Those hashes are used for compatibility checks, and changing the hash will lead to data corruption in the end.

> I figured out that the .msg file on the robot has one line missing, which is present on the .msg file on my pc. This results in the md5 hash to be different. So I tried deleting the line in the .msg file on my pc and "catkin build" my package.

This would be one way to work-around the version difference, but note that this leads to a difficult situation: you should rebuild all packages that use this message to make sure that no (de)serialisation issues crop up. From the description in your question, I guess that won't be possible.

Disregarding that, for now it would probably make sense to try and figure out why `rosmsg md5 ..` seems to not pick up the edited version of your file. Where did you actually "delete the line in the .msg file"? In a package in your Catkin workspace, or in `/opt/ros/kinetic/..`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0